# What is the expected value when two dice are thrown?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

> Two dice are thrown and a random variable X is taken as a sum of the
> values on both dice plus a product of those values. What's EX?

Could you please check if I constructed pmf correctly?

Is my answer correct?

| outcomes | (1,1) | (1,2) (2,1) | (1,3) (3,1) (2,2) | (1,3) (3,1) (2,2) | (1,4) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1) | (1,4) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2+1=3 | 3+2=5 | 4+3=7 | 4+4=8 | 5+4=9 | 5+6=11 | ... |
| P(X) | 1/36 | 2/36 | 3/36 | 3/36 | 4/36 | 4/36 | ... |

E(X)= $\frac {3+10+21+24+36+44+60+70+75+48+82+102+105+108+116+100+115+120}{36} = \frac {1239}{36} $

Comment: You have the case $(2,2)$ twice (among others).  Anyway, it's a lot easier to do this by linearity (and using the independence of the two rolls).

Comment: Why do you group outcomes by the sum of the two dice when $X$ also depends on the product?

Comment: You can't group $(1,3), (3,1), (2,2)$ together since they have different $X$ values. Instead $P(X=7) = \frac{2}{36}$, $P(X=8) = \frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: This can also be solved algebraically rather than writing out all the cases.

Comment: Worth noting that your answer is far too high.  Very few outcomes yield an $X$ that high, common sense should have planted a red flag.

Comment: Note that $A+B+AB=(A+1)(B+1)-1$  so likely to be something like $4.5^2-1$

Comment: I get X values of [3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 17, 17, 19, 19, 20, 20, 23, 23, 24, 27, 27, 29, 29, 34, 34, 35, 41, 41, 48], which averages to 19.25.

Comment: @Joe  >   Why do you group outcomes by the sum of the two dice when X also depends on the product?    In the table It is not only sum. It is sum and sum of their product (as it was stated in the task)

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you did: you put the outcomes in the first row by sum, BUT then duplicated outcomes to make multiple columns - one per product. I think that's a confusing way to arrange everything. In fact, you seem to have confused yourself by that arrangement, which is why your $P(X)$ row is incorrect.  I think that @lulu also did not understand your grouping, hence the comment about (2,2) being on the list twice.

Comment: Now I seem to understand my mistake in the table. It should look like one outcome (1,3) (3,1) (2,2)  but two x values 7 and 8 
with different probabilities 2/36 and 1/36. But I still can't get how to avoid making such a big table and use more algebra because I'm "philologist").

Comment: Your chart appears to be incomprehensible.  If you want to go case by case, do that.  There's only $36$ cases, easy to list them all.  But, really, it's much better to just think about it.  Expectation is linear (always) and multiplicative (at least for independent variables) so $E[X]=E[A+B+AB]=2E[A]+E[A]^2$, where $A,B$ denote the two throws, so $E[A]=E[B]=3.5$